# Unity Op amp Question Gain and Resistances

Tags: operational-amplifier, decibel, unity-gain

[image]

The Question asks what is the gain in dB and also what are the input and output resistances

I know the gain is 1 so dB that would be equal to 0 dB

But I am confused on how to find the input and output resistances.

I think you have to assume it is an ideal op, so would that mean the input resistance is infinite and output resistance is zero?

Comment: Yes.  You've got this sorted.

Comment: Yup! Too short for an answer, or a comment unless I add this!